# What is the difference between these two find algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

I have these two find algorithm which look the same to me. Can anyone help me out why they are actually different?

```
Find ( x ) :
    if x.parent = x then 
        return x
    else 
        return Find ( x.parent )
```

vs

```
Find ( x ) :
    if x.parent = x then 
        return x
    else 
        x.parent <- Find(x.parent)
        return x.parent
```

I interpret the first one as

```
 int i = 0;    
 return i++;
```

while the second one as

```
int i = 0;
int tmp = i++;
return tmp
```

which are exactly the same to me.

Comment: removing java tag - `x.parent <- Find(x.parent)` ain't java

Comment: `x.parent <- Find(x.parent)` modifies `x.parent`, which the first one doesn't do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like [Disjoint-set data structure](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=disjointDataStructure).

Now to the question:

For the sake of clarity first version is `FindA`, second is `FindB`.

Suppose you have structure:

```
 0
 |
 1
 |
 2
 |
...
 n
```

First call to `FindA(n)` will return 0 in O(n), second call will return 0 in O(n) and so on.

If you call `FindB(n)` it will return 0 in O(n), but will also modify structure:

```
    0
 / /|\
1 2...n
```

Now second call to FindB(n) will return 0 in O(1). More over FindB(k) will return 0 in O(1).

Comment: To add to your very good answer: While the first results in `O(n)` or `O(logn)` (implementation dependent) the short-cutting technique reduces the complexity to `O(a(n))` where `a(n)` is the inverse of [ackerman function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), which is very slowly growing, and practically <=3 for almost any realistic input size.

Answer (score 2):

The second one will change the value of x.parent as a side effect to the result of find